# Force of gravity at quantum level is indetermined?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, quantum-gravity, singularities

**Newton's law of Universal Gravitation** states that **any** two bodies in the universe attract each other with a force that is directly proportional to the product of their masses and inversely proportional to the square of the distance between them.

$$F = \frac{GmM}{R^2}$$

$F$ is the force of gravity.

$m$ is the light mass.

$M$ is the heavy mass.

$R$ is the distance.

$G$ is a gravitational constant = 6.67384 $\times$ 10<sup>-11</sup> m<sup>3</sup> kg<sup>-1</sup> s<sup>-2</sup>.

From the above mentioned equation the force of gravity $F$ becomes stronger if any of the mass increases, since nerds love to treat elementary particles (they have mass) as point-like if we reduce the distance $R$ to $0$ we will get $F = \infty$ (sound weird).

**Question**

Can't I apply Newton's laws of **universal** gravitation at quantum level? Or do these particles actually have radius?

Comment: *"Can't I apply Newton's laws of universal gravitation at quantum level?"* What do you mean by that? You don't "apply the Coulomb law of electrostatic force at quantum level", either.

Comment: @ACuriousMind therefore this is how classical physics becomes weird when applied to point-like particles? I simply want to find the gravitational force between these two elementary particles as they close in on each other.

Comment: Quantum mechanically, the force would become an operator like eveything else. See [Force in quantum mechanics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46544/50583)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation work when particles are very close?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/403537/does-newtons-law-of-universal-gravitation-work-when-particles-are-very-close)